# Segurança e autenticação de login no Ionic 3 usando token de acesso gerado pelo PHP

Tags: php, segurança, ionic2, autenticação, ionic3

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo onde o usuário pode efetuar o login fornecendo o seu e-mail e sua senha. Após isso, eu faço uma requisição ao meu servidor `PHP` que verifica no banco de dados se os dados existem e estão corretos (se sim, retorna um `status = true` e mais alguns dados, se não, retorna `status = false`).

Acontece que eu quero que o usuário não precise fazer login toda vez em que abrir o app, porém, qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Sei que não devo salvar o e-mail e a senha através do [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) (utilizo somente para dados não sigilosos, como: nome, sobrenome, foto, etc).
Dei uma olhada também no [Secure Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/) (para armazenar os dados sigilosos, apenas), contudo, ele necessita que o usuário tenha um certo nível de segurança no seu dispositivo (senha na tela de bloqueio) para funcionar, e isso é inviável para o meu app. (nem todos utilizam senhas na tela de bloqueio)

Pelas minhas pesquisas, vi que a maioria das recomendações seria, ao efetuar o login, o servidor `PHP` gerar um token de acesso, armazená-lo no banco de dados (atrelando o token ao usuário), retorná-lo ao app e salvá-lo no `Ionic Storage`, e então, toda vez em que o app for aberto, enviar esse token através da requisição e verificar no banco de dados se o mesmo existe e é válido.

Diante disso, eu pensei no seguinte:

Salvar o id do usuário (vou utilizar ele em quase todas as ações no meu app) e o token no `Ionic Storage`, então, no momento em que for feita a autenticação, verificar se o token existe para o id fornecido, pois isso descarta a possibilidade de algum usuário mal intencionado acessar o Storage do app, simplesmente alterar o id e se passar pelo usuário correspondente ao id fornecido, porque além do id, ele teria que obter o token gerado para aquele usuário.

Essa é uma forma segura de fazer uma autenticação? Se não, como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essa é uma forma segura de fazer uma autenticação? Se não, como fazer?

Defina seus objetivos, sem isso é impossível determinar o que é seguro. Elevar a altura do muro da sua casa não dificulta arrombar o portão.

---

Existem algumas incógnitas:

1. Qual o tamanho do token?
2. Como o token é informado para o cliente?
3. Como irá comparar o token?
4. Como o token é gerado?

---

Com a informação que foi dita: qualquer pessoa que ler os dados do banco de dados, que escute a comunicação ou que tenha acesso físico ao dispositivo do cliente terá como fazer o login, se passando por ele. Qualquer pessoa ainda poderá prever o token gerado, poderá mensurar o tempo gasto para cada tentativa e ainda poderá resgatar tokens salvos de discos abandonados.

Se você acredita que todos os problemas anteriores são "insignificantes", então você tem algo seguro. Se não, você tem algo inseguro.

---

Uma construção bem simples que iria resolver razoavelmente todos os problemas seria:

1. [APP] Utilize HTTPS, TLS 1.2, não trafegue informação sob HTTP.
2. [SRV] Especifique no aplicativo quais são as chaves públicas confiáveis (adicione algumas chaves reservas, claro).

Quando fizer o login:

1. [APP] Gere uma chave Ed25519 (ou confie em uma curva da NIST).
2. [APP] Informe o e-mail/senha e a chave pública (extraída do passo 1).
3. [SRV] Verifique e-mail/senha, não é o escopo aqui. Se for verdadeira acrescente a chave pública como confiável para tal e-mail.

Quando for "usar o token":

1. [SRV] Gere um desafio. Crie 128 bits aleatórios, de maneira uniforme e indistinguível de um resultado verdadeiramente aleatório.
2. [APP] Assine o desafio usando EdDSA e informe o `id` do usuário.
3. [SRV] Verifica, em tempo constante, se a assinatura condiz com alguma chave pública daquele usuário e se nunca foi utilizado tal desafio anteriormente.

*Adicionalmente você pode encriptar a chave, exigindo uma senha ou PIN. Isso impediria que alguém com acesso físico, com pouco tempo disponível, consiga realizar o login. Além disso iria dificultar um ataque offline, dando possibilidade do usuário revogar a chave.*